# Implementing np.subtract.outer for index of array([[array .... structure in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have the following set of indices;

```
ind = array([[array([0, 1, 4])],
           [array([0, 1, 2, 5])],
           [array([1, 2, 3, 6])],
           [array([2, 3, 7])],
           [array([0, 4, 5, 8])],
           [array([1, 4, 5, 6, 9])],
           [array([ 2,  5,  6,  7, 10])],
           [array([ 3,  6,  7, 11])],
           [array([ 4,  8,  9, 12])],
           [array([ 5,  8,  9, 10, 13])],
           [array([ 6,  9, 10, 11, 14])],
           [array([ 7, 10, 11, 15])],
           [array([ 8, 12, 13])],
           [array([ 9, 12, 13, 14])],
           [array([10, 13, 14, 15])],
           [array([11, 14, 15])]])
```

of `X`, which is shown below

```
X = array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ],
           [ 0.33333333,  0.        ],
           [ 0.66666667,  0.        ],
           [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
           [ 0.        ,  0.33333333],
           [ 0.33333333,  0.33333333],
           [ 0.66666667,  0.33333333],
           [ 1.        ,  0.33333333],
           [ 0.        ,  0.66666667],
           [ 0.33333333,  0.66666667],
           [ 0.66666667,  0.66666667],
           [ 1.        ,  0.66666667],
           [ 0.        ,  1.        ],
           [ 0.33333333,  1.        ],
           [ 0.66666667,  1.        ],
           [ 1.        ,  1.        ]])
```

Is there an efficient way without using `forloop` to get the following matrices;

```
A = [X[0,0]-X[0,0]  X[0,0]-X[1,0]  X[0,0]-X[4,0]
    X[1,0]-X[0,0]  X[1,0]-X[1,0]  X[1,0]-X[2,0] X[1,0]-X[5,0]
    X[2,0]-X[1,0]  X[2,0]-X[2,0]  X[2,0]-X[3,0] X[2,0]-X[6,0] 
    ...
    ...
    ...
   X[15,0]-X[11,0] X[15,0]-X[14,0] X[15,0]-X[15,0] ]
```

I have already tried np.subtract.outer and np.subtract. The `ind` structure is very difficult to work with (in terms of simply using `X[ind,0]` let say). I prefer not to change the `ind` structure. Looking for a cleaver way without using `forloop` to achieve matrix `A`.

Thanks for your help

Comment: wouldn't the last line be `X[15,0]-X[11,0] X[15,0]-X[14,0] X[15,0]-X[15,0] `

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you transform you array of indices like:

```
ind = ind.flatten()
```

you can obtain what you want doing:

```
a = X[:,0]
ans = [np.ones(len(i))*a[0]-a[i] for i in ind]
```

With your original definition of `ind` you must use `i[0]` instead.

---

EDIT: this can be improved to (as suggested by @Jaime):

```
ans = [a[0] - a[i] for i in ind]
```

Comment: Either `[a[0]-a[i] for i in ind]` or `a - [a[i] for i in ind]` acieve the same and are cleaner and (probably) faster.

Comment: The problem is rewriting the `ind` . As `ind` is a result of a function that gives that structure. Otherwise this is much simpler as you pointed out. If `ind` has the structure you changed to, you can simply use `np.subtract.outer`.

Comment: @madf19 please check the edit where I added how to transform your `ind` array to a flattened format that will probably make your life easier...

Comment: `ind.flatten()` dose not work well for `array([[array(...`. Thats exactly what I am trying to do in very efficient way by changing the format of `ind` to something like `(array(..), array(..))` by some built-in functions in python. Also would like to use some biult in functions in python for instance 'np.subtract.outer'. The ind and X are very large in order of 10**6 and using forloop is not an option

Comment: @Jaime thanks for your help. let me rephrase my question, let say what is the most efficient way without using for to convert
`ind = array([[array([0, 1, 4])],
           [array([0, 1, 2, 5])],
           [array([1, 2, 3, 6])],
           [array([2, 3, 7])],
           [array([0, 4, 5, 8])],
           [array([1, 4, 5, 6, 9])],
           [array([ 2,  5,  6,  7, 10])]])`

to
`(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]),array([0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 5, 1, 3, 4, 0, 4, 3, 1, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 3, 7, 6,4, 8, 2, 5]))`

Comment: @SaulloCastro  thank you for your help. please see the rephrase question above.

Comment: @madf19 I did not understand your rephrased question and it seems to be totally different than your original one... perhaps you should post it as a new question...